# QGraphicsItem disappears when calling setPos from a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qgraphicsitem

I have two types of ­­­­­­­­­­`QGraphicsItem­­­­­­`s on a `QGraphicsView`, one of those two types are in the scene like grid with z-index 1, the other ones, ants, are on top of them with z-index 2. When starting the program, I set all ants to position 0,0 and add them to the scene. But then I start moving those ants from another Thread by calling `setPos()` on them - and then my computer eats the ants! They disapper at their old position, but don't appear at their new position. The new position is inside the scene.

Here is the code of `Ant` class (that inherits `QGraphicsItem`):

```
#include "ant.h"
#include "constants.h"

#include <QPainter>

Ant::Ant()
{
    setZValue(2);
}

QRectF Ant::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRect(QPoint(0,0), G_FIELD_RECT_SIZE);
}

void Ant::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *item, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(item)
    Q_UNUSED(widget)

    QBrush b = painter->brush();
    if (food())
        painter->setBrush(Qt::blue);
    else
        painter->setBrush(Qt::black);
    painter->drawEllipse(2,3, G_FIELD_RECT_WIDTH - 4, G_FIELD_RECT_HEIGHT - 6);
    painter->setBrush(b);
}
```

After a bit more testing, I found out that everything is working as long as I call `setPos` from the Qt Event Thread. As soon as I call it in an custom thread, the ants disappear. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: You should keep UI stuff all in the main thread. There is like a design limitation in Qt in this regard. You can offload calculations to another thread, but all GUI interaction MUST be in the main thread,

Comment: @ddriver The Ant class actually is only for graphics stuff, another class running on another thread is calling the `setPos` method that was causing trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must go back to the main thread to do the `setPos`. As commented by ddriver, you should not modify GUI from a thread (you usually get `qDebug` messages when doing so, didn't you get any in your debugger window?).

You just need to:

- Add a new signal to your `Ant` class (like `signalSetPos( QPoint pos )`)
- Add a new slot to your `Ant` class (like `doSetPos( QPoint pos )`). This slot implementation simply calls `setPos(pos)`.
- Connect them using `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` (fifth parameter of the `connect` function, for GUI update, `Qt::QueuedConnection` may be preferable because it won't block your thread).
- From the thread where you used to do `setPos( newPos )`, just do emit `signalSetPos( newPos )`. Then, `doSetPos` will be executed (later if you used `Qt::QueuedConnection`, right away if you used `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`) from the main thread.

Check this post for more information about emitting signals from threads:
[Qt - emit a signal from a c++ thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982324/qt-emit-a-signal-from-a-c-thread/24982490#24982490)

Comment: Yes I did get debug messages `QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread`, didn't know they are related to that problem

Comment: Maybe `QGraphicsItem­­­­­­::setPos` uses a startTimer. You could search for this message in Qt code and put a breakpoint here to see when and why you reach it.